# CMAKE and SFML 2.5.1 missing dependencies

Tags: cmake, sfml

I am trying to add sfml to my cmake project.

sfml-network and sfml-system are working correctly but when i add sfml-graphics or
sfml-window or sfml-audio i am getting errors:

Error: sfml found but some of its dependencies are missing FreeType OpanAl VorbisFile VorbisEnc Vorbis Ogg FLAC

[image: error image]

My CmakeList file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Glitter)

option(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF)
option(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF)
option(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF)
add_subdirectory(Glitter/Vendor/glfw)

option(ASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS OFF)
option(ASSIMP_BUILD_SAMPLES OFF)
option(ASSIMP_BUILD_TESTS OFF)
add_subdirectory(Glitter/Vendor/assimp)

option(BUILD_BULLET2_DEMOS OFF)
option(BUILD_CPU_DEMOS OFF)
option(BUILD_EXTRAS OFF)
option(BUILD_OPENGL3_DEMOS OFF)
option(BUILD_UNIT_TESTS OFF)
add_subdirectory(Glitter/Vendor/bullet)

add_subdirectory(Glitter/Vendor/SFML)


if(MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /W4")
else()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++11")
    if(NOT WIN32)
        set(GLAD_LIBRARIES dl)
    endif()
endif()

include_directories(Glitter/Headers/
                    Glitter/Vendor/assimp/include/
                    Glitter/Vendor/bullet/src/
                    Glitter/Vendor/glad/include/
                    Glitter/Vendor/glfw/include/
                    Glitter/Vendor/glm/
                    Glitter/Vendor/stb/
                    Glitter/Vendor/SFML/inlcude/
                    )

file(GLOB VENDORS_SOURCES Glitter/Vendor/glad/src/glad.c)
file(GLOB PROJECT_HEADERS Glitter/Headers/*.hpp)
file(GLOB PROJECT_SOURCES Glitter/Sources/*.cpp)
file(GLOB PROJECT_SHADERS Glitter/Shaders/*.comp
                          Glitter/Shaders/*.frag
                          Glitter/Shaders/*.geom
                          Glitter/Shaders/*.vert)
file(GLOB PROJECT_CONFIGS CMakeLists.txt
                          Readme.md
                         .gitattributes
                         .gitignore
                         .gitmodules)

source_group("Headers" FILES ${PROJECT_HEADERS})
source_group("Shaders" FILES ${PROJECT_SHADERS})
source_group("Sources" FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
source_group("Vendors" FILES ${VENDORS_SOURCES})

set(SFML_DIR "Glitter/Vendor/SFML/")
set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)
find_package(SFML COMPONENTS network system audio window graphics REQUIRED)




add_definitions(-DGLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
                -DPROJECT_SOURCE_DIR=\"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}\")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCES} ${PROJECT_HEADERS}
                               ${PROJECT_SHADERS} ${PROJECT_CONFIGS}
                               ${VENDORS_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} assimp glfw
                      ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} ${GLAD_LIBRARIES}
                      BulletDynamics BulletCollision LinearMath sfml-network sfml-system sfml-window sfml-graphic sfml-window)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow we want error logs in **textual** form. Among other things, it allows others, who is faced with the similar problem, to find the answer via searching. Please, [edit] your post and insert the error message as a text; you may format that text as a code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the static version of SFML you'll also have to allow CMake to find the listed dependencies. For Windows, these should appear where you've installed/unpacked SFML. For other operating systems, you'll have to install them manually.

You can also look in your `CMakeCache.txt` file and look for the entries for those libraries, setting those paths manually.